# Is there a way to have a valueBox use a reactive variable made in the server and create a popup or modal?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

I'm wondering how one would have a user input a csv and have a valueBox appear with the number of rows contained in that csv. That valueBox should also have the ability to display a modal of the data the user inputted when clicked.

The issue that's being had is that I'm able to get the valueBox to display the number of rows but not the modal when clicked.

This is what is working to display the number of rows but the modal pop up doesn't work.

I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test Bed"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      fileInput("file", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      valueBoxOutput("fulldata")
    )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    read.csv(input$file$datapath)
  })
  
  output$fulldata <- renderValueBox({
    div(id = "clickdiv",
        valueBox(nrow(data()), subtitle = "Total Rows"))
  })
  
  onclick("clickdiv", showModal(modalDialog(
    title = "Test",
    renderDataTable(data())
  )))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Soo... I didn't test it yet, but I could notice that

`valueBox(nrow(data()), subtitle = "Total Rows")`

and

`renderDataTable(data())`

You put data(), and I think what you want is just data ( Exe: `valueBox(nrow(data), subtitle = "Total Rows")`. If still doesn't work I'll try coding

Comment: I've just now tested this and it still is behaving the same way. Let me know what you find when you try coding it. Thank you!